# CrossDomain in UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, cross-domain

Hey erveryone, 
im currently working on an app which should contain an uiwebview to show a website with some reports (used a website because we want to show it also on android). 
The data for the reports were loaded from another page by ajax with cross domain headers (Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers are set) and it worked fine in firefox, chrome and the other standard browsers. 
It also worked on mobile safari. 
But nevertheless this did not work in the uiwebview.
The uiwebview is loading and displaying the website but without the data.

The base part of the code is :

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[APPCONTEXT.service reportGetWebPageURL]]]
```

Should i have to set any headers with the website request or is it perhaps not possible to load the data ?

Thanks for helping me with this issue

**EDIT**

```
[APPCONTEXT.service reportGetWebPageURL] // NSURL*
```

Cannot post images so this should help to understand the system.

UIWebView (Request to show Website1)--> Website1 (AJAX Request for data to show)--> Website2

Comment: what does it contains, give some example and plz..

Comment: reportGetWebPageURL -- ? , it is the method or else..

Comment: it is the method to get a NSURL Object like `[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.de"]`

Comment: it contains APPCONTEXT.service..?

Comment: yes, APPCONTEXT is a reference to an object that contains my service features. in this service there is a method to get my NSURL Object. i could also write the same code as you did below but i have a model which holds my constants etc.

Comment: k do onething , first u get the all data and store with one NSString and finally add the string into **[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:strName]];**

Comment: but how does it solve the problem. the url which i inserted, gets loaded by the uiwebview and i see website1 with empty diagrams. only the data itself, which should be shown in the diagrams is not working right in uiwebview.